# How to run gdb with -quiet in xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, gdb

I'm a newbie, so you'll have to explain this pretty clearly.

I'm looking for a way for Xcode to automatically run gdb with the -quiet command so that it doesn't show startup text. I tried to edit the /Developer/usr/bin/gdb executable by adding -q to the exec lines at the end after "$gdb" in this code (somebody mentioned doing that elsewhere, though it didn't work):

```
if [ -n "$requested_arch" -a $translate_mode -eq 0 ]
then
  exec $translate_binary "$gdb" --arch "$requested_arch" "$@"
else
  exec $translate_binary "$gdb" $osabiopts "$@"
fi
```

So any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, it is already being invoked with -q.

This is what Xcode eventually exec's (iPhone example):

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-i386-apple-darwin --arch i386 --interp=mi1 -q
```

Running that command in Terminal will hide the initial output, but not in Xcode's console debugger.